# Extract last K characters from a string in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a string that looks like this

```
my $str1 = "ACGGATATTGA";
my $str2 = "alex";
```

What I want to do is to extract last three characters 
from each of that.

```
$out1 = "TGA";
$out2 = "lex";
```

How can I do it in Perl?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove the last seven characters of a hash value in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846257/how-can-i-remove-the-last-seven-characters-of-a-hash-value-in-perl)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html):

```
$out1 = substr($str1, -3);
```

Comment: can you do this within a print function?